# Text in div gets input from the form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

following is my div and i want to know how can i get the input from the form lets say from textfield 'name' and display that input name instead of jhon in the following div, Kindly help!!

```
<div id='faix' class="bg4 w460 h430 tac poa dpn ">
                    <h4 class="fwb fs22 cf3 mb5 ff3 mt150 ">Thank you John for contacting us!</h4><h4 class="fwb fs22 cf3 mb5 ff3"> We will get in touch with you shortly.</h4>
                </div>
```

Comment: Really hard to understand what you wan't to achieve.

Comment: probably posting your appropriate html relaed to your issue would help

Comment: just the entered name from the form appear instead of 'jhon' in the above div some thing like $('#name').val();

Comment: THANX ALL FOR HELPING ME OUT!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input id="name" name="name" value=""/>
</form>
```

js:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(){
  $("#faix h4.mt150").empty().append("Thank you "+$("#name").val()+" for contacting us!");
    return false;
})​
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/BPXpb/1/

Comment: your code is doing it right just one problem when i strike enter it changes up the jhon... i want when the user click on submit then the meassage appears along with the name he mentioned in my contact form...

Answer (score 1):

See http://jsfiddle.net/wfAgb/

```
//get the name
var Name = $('#name').val();
//replace John with the new name
$('.mt150').text($('.mt150').text().replace('John', Name));
```

You could with great benefit make span arounde the name so you can change it directly.

```
<h4 class="fwb fs22 cf3 mb5 ff3 mt150 ">Thank you <span id="formName">John</span> for contacting us!</h4>
```

And then do

```
var Name = $('#name').val();
$('#formName').text(Name);
```